# Cannot reshape array of size 1 into shape (1,224,224,3)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing

I am trying to reshape separate arrays of three components each Y - U - V into a YUV array. The size of this array input 64x64 and then will be resized to 224x224. How should I do it correctly?

This is for my input data before training a CNN network. So, the following is the way I use to do it.

```
orgY = np.loadtxt(path)
orgU = np.loadtxt(path)
orgV = np.loadtxt(path)

originalYUV = np.dstack((orgY, orgU, orgV))

originalYUV = array(originalYUV).reshape(1, 224, 224, 3)
```

When I run it, this shows me: ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1 into shape (1,224,224,3). How should I fix it? I am afraid the code is wrong when I use `np.dstack` as I even cannot call `width = originalYUV.shape[0]`

Comment: There is problem in your `originalYUV` creation I think. I run similar code with same shapes and it works. maybe you should change `orgB` with `orgV`

Comment: oops, my mistake. But that was a typo when writing this question. I'll update